# Need to add two hour in a column while creating create statement in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am creating a table in that i am getting the entry time by now() function. Every data will be valid for 2 two hours. So I need to automatically add the time in the endtime colums

```
CREATE TABLE `mdiner_test`.`table_assign_mgr` (
  `resid` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `custname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Guest',
  `custemail` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'info@si.com',
  `custmobile` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '98989898',
  `isactive` TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `starttime` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  `endtime` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL 2 HOUR),
  PRIMARY KEY (`resid`));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like an unnecessary column but you might be able to use generated columns(depending on your version of mysql) https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html but you would lose the ability to provide an endtime.

```
drop table if exists t;
CREATE TABLE t (
  `resid` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `custname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Guest',
  `custemail` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'info@si.com',
  `custmobile` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '98989898',
  `isactive` TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `starttime` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  `endtime` DATETIME as (DATE_ADD(starttime, INTERVAL 2 HOUR)),
  PRIMARY KEY (`resid`));

insert into t(resid) values (1);

select * from t;

+-------+----------+-------------+------------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| resid | custname | custemail   | custmobile | isactive | starttime           | endtime             |
+-------+----------+-------------+------------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
|     1 | Guest    | info@si.com | 98989898   |        1 | 2019-07-16 08:27:58 | 2019-07-16 10:27:58 |
+-------+----------+-------------+------------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

If you cannot use generated columns you could use a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

As per the latest [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html), it does not look like you can achieve it by creating the table on the fly :

> The default value specified in a DEFAULT clause must be a literal
>   constant; it cannot be a function or an expression. This means, for
>   example, that you cannot set the default for a date column to be the
>   value of a function such as NOW() or CURRENT_DATE. The exception is
>   that, for TIMESTAMP and DATETIME columns, you can specify
>   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as the default. See Section 11.3.4, “Automatic
>   Initialization and Updating for TIMESTAMP and DATETIME”.

May be you can go ahead with P. Salmon's solution in that case.